# Can I use anycast or latency-based routing with Cloudflare?

Tags: amazon-ec2, latency, cloudflare

I'm currently using Cloudflare as my DNS pointing to load-balancers in EC2. The two key features I'm missing with this setup that I really want to add are:

1. Send users trying to access my site to the nearest backend server to them to fulfill the request.
2. Health-checks and automatic failover, so if I have many servers that could fulfill the request, and one of them goes down, it should be taken out of the pool, and no users should be sent there.

Can I accomplish this with Cloudflare? Do I need to use Cloudflare + something like Route53, or do I just need to switch off Cloudflare to something else altogether?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare already uses [Anycast](https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-brief-anycast-primer/).

We don't automatically failover at this time (something we're looking at), but you could probably build a script via our API to pull an IP out if it goes down.

We do support the round robin entries for multiple servers now, but there's no way to force it so a visitor from a certain area hits a certain server in your DNS settings.

Comment: Do you guys recommend using route53 behind the scenes or anything like that to manage not hitting boxes that are down? Having each of my boxes be a point of failure or managing this with a script seems very dangerous.

Comment: @damoncloudflare - 2.5yrs later... any progress on forcing a certain server within a geographic region?

Comment: @Corey Did you find a solution? I just spoke about this to stackpath techies. But couldn't get a solid answer.

Comment: @Ajay Singh no - never got an answer to this.